# Write permission to mounted drive (through Samba)

Tags: file-permissions, arch-linux

I have the following mount point. (I did not configuration aside from plugging in the external USB HD.):

```
# mount -t fuseblk
/dev/sda1 on /media/FreeAgent_GoFlex_Drive type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,bl)
```

How might I make this drive writable to authenticated users (ssh and eventually Samba)? Do I edit the /etc/rc.conf?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Since the filesystem appears to be NTFS (through `ntfs-3g`), you should be able to just use

  ```
  chmod a+rwX /media/FreeAgent_GoFlex_Drive
  ```

  as root.
- If not, you can add a `fstab` entry for the filesystem:

  ```
  UUID=<uuid>   /media/<mountpoint>     ntfs-3g    fmask=022,dmask=0
  ```

  Replace `<uuid>` with the UUID listed by `blkid` for your disk; do not simply use `/dev/sda1` as this name may change after reboot, whereas UUIDs are constant. Also replace `<mountpoint>` with a directory name; possibly "`FreeAgent_GoFlex_Drive`", or something more convenient.

Comment: Thank you. Using root, I'm now able to write to the drive.